# Azure DataFactory DataFlow json source wrong types

Tags: azure-data-factory

I created a dataflow and a new dataset with json files from Data lake.
The schema has correct types:

[image: dataset]

But when I set this dataset as a source of the dataflow, all integers become strings, as I see it on Projection tab:

[image]

Though boolean type remains.
How can I fix this?
I need to have original types.
If it is not possible, is there any activity to cast columns to different type?
Also, "Import projection" is disabled for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on debug, clear the schema in the dataset, and then import projection